# jQuery UI Form won't resubmit on F5 even after disabling ajax

Tags: jquery-mobile

So, I have a form which has a similar markup as the below form:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="/send/confirm-and-pay" method="POST" data-ajax="false">
```

The problem is that after the form submission, I show a next page where if the user refreshes the page like by pressing F5, it wont ask to resubmit the form again and the previous "post" request is now shown as a "get" request in the firebug.

The firebug output is:

```
1) On clicking on submit: "Post confirm-and-pay 200OK"
2) Now, on pressing F5: "Get confirm-and-pay 200OK"
```

Now to mention that all the values that form sends to the action "confirm-and-pay" are lost so on the page, it shows nothing.

Any help would be aprreciated.

Comment: I think experts here will help you out if you post more of your code and context.

Comment: @MayuMayooresan The code is given above as its working perfectly fine when user clicks on the submit button. After if the page is refreshed, normally browser asks with a confirm box whether user really wants to refresh as all the data would be resubmitted. That thing is not happening on my end as on pressing the F5 button, the page refreshes but in firebug it shows a get request and all the form data is lost. Hope I am making some sense here.

Comment: @gaurav did you ever solve this?  I'm running in to the same issue with some jQuery Mobile code.

Comment: @Zac Sorry I couldn't find a solution at that time, so continued with the get requests.

Answer (score 0):

I added this code to change some settings, like this:

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
```

Now, when you press 'F5', the request is POSTed. You can try this.